# Encrypt site_id in URL show details

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have database

```
site_id | site_name | site_status
1       | site A    | 1
2       | site B    | 1
3       | site C    | 1
```

SiteController

```
public function show(site $site,$id)
{
    $site = site::where('site_id',$id)->first();
    // return $id;
    return view('master.site.show',compact('site'));
}
```

User.php (Model)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Site extends Model
{
    protected $table = "site";
    protected $primaryKey = 'site_id';

    protected $fillable = ['site_name','site_status','created_by','created_date'];
}
```

Routes.

```
Route::get('/site_show/{id}', 'SiteController@show')->name('site_show');
```

View.

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('site_show',['id'=>$site->site_id]) }}"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> Show</a>
```

please help me step by step when I click Show button in show.blade, url will display http://localhost/myproject/public/site_show/asndlah9q8yasa not http://localhost/myproject/public/site_show/2

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` Laravel helper function.

your controller

```
public function show(site $site,$id)
{
    $site = site::where('site_id',decrypt($id))->first();
    // return $id;
    return view('master.site.show',compact('site'));
}
```

Your views

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('site_show',['id'=>encrypt($site->site_id)]) }}"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> Show</a>
```